# Rolling two dice

Tags: probability

Two dice are rolled. What is the probability of getting a sum of $9$ given the first die shows $5$?

Using conditional probability,

A: sum is $9$

B: 1st die shows $5$

$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(\textrm{sum is 9 and 1st die is 5})}{P (\text{1st die is 5})} =\frac{1/36}{6/36} = \frac{1}{6}$$ Well, the answer given is $2/3 $ which I don't understand.

Kindly explain.

Comment: Given that the first die shows $5$, for the sum to be $9$, the second die must be $4$. There's clearly a $\frac 1 6$ chance of that happening. How can the answer be $\frac 2 3$?

Comment: You are either reading the problem wrong, or whoever gave you the answer is wrong. Go reread the problem and if you have intrepreted it correctly, then they are wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the answer was mistyped and was supposed to be $\frac 2 {36}$, which would be the probability of getting $4, 5$ as the values on 2 dice without regard to order. By the phrasing as given, I would not consider this to be a correct answer either, but possibly that is a difference between the problem as stated here, and as originally given.

Answer (score 0):

The stated question seems unusually simple, even for a drill exercise.
Maybe the intended question was to find the probability that the
sum is $at\; most$ 9, given that the first (red) die shows 5.  Explorations using simulation of a million tosses of a red die and a green die:

```
 r = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)
 g = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)
 t = r + g
 mean(t[r==5] == 9)  # exactly 9
 ## 0.1660904
 mean(t[r==5] >= 9)  # at least 9
 ## 0.4991776
 mean(t[r==5] <= 9)  # at most 9
 ## 0.6669128
```